Car dies at a stop sign?
2019 dodge gran caravan with 75000 miles. I drove up to a stop sign and stopped. It seems to shut off. Turned it off and back on and it worked. Starting to get concerned the transmission is going bad. There’s no slippage or clunks when I’m driving. No check engine light.
